# Create New SQL Column With Smaller Buckets (Based on Text, not Numbers)

Tags: sql, hana

I have a column in SQL that has multiple "Definitions" but I would like anything that starts with DEF to just be the generic "Definition".

What can I put in my Select statement to have this converted?

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when current_output like 'DEF%' then 'DEFINITION'
             else current_output
        end) as desired_output
```